# Should I use branch or create new sandbox in git?

Tags: git

I have automated a few test cases and pushed them for review. However I need to continue developing other testcases in the same code. I cannot create a new sandbox everytime as my changes are not really in the stream and hence I dont get them in my newly created local. Is branching really the way to work? If so how do I keep my currently working changes private and isolated so that nobody is aware of it.. Not even the master?

Answer (score 0):

Git is a decentralized version control system. If you don't push your branch to your remote then its local and you can work on it.

So you have to create a new branch for every change.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell